# Бот в телеграм не работает автономно

Tags: веб-программирование

нужен совет новичку

в pycharm - написал базового бота-попугая, перестает работать как закрываю закрываю pycharm в ПК

как сделать так чтобы бот работал автономно?

Comment: Положить его на сервер. Бот должен где-то исполняться, иначе, увы, никак.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала нужно **приобрести** сервер.

После покупки, подключитесь по SSH, к серверу и начните установку необходимых компонентов(Python и т.д.)

*P.S. По простому запросу в гугле(напр.: как установить Python на Ubuntu), можно найти мануалы по установке необходимых компонентов :D*

Есть ещё вариант с хостингом, который поддерживает Python скрипты. Тут куда проще, нужно залить файлы на хостинг.